# Unity 5 - Textures look strange in Deferred Rendering

Tags: textures, rendering, lighting, unity

I've created an exterior terrain scene in Unity 5 which features lots of trees and grass but some textures look awful and I'm wondering why. Please see the attached image:

[image]

This texture problem is especially obvious at night (I'm using Time of Day unity asset for Day/Night cycle) but also during day light it doesn't look good. The tree bark looks like plastic and also the ground textures are too bright and lack contrast. Stone texture on the other hand look perfectly fine.

Can somebody point me into the right direction of what I'm doing wrong here with my lighting and rendering?

Comment: You can view and change the shader (a small program that is used to determine how an object is drawn) used for each material on its relevant component

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the shader. The tree bark looked fine in Unity 5.1 but since I updated to 5.2 they look like above. Also if I for example change to the Speedtree shader nothing changes.

Comment: Interestingly if I switch to Forward rendering, the trees look OK. In Deferred they change to like in the above above. The sand looks like crap no matter what. At night it is so bright it looks like snow.

Comment: Ok, the ground textures have been fixed by setting the Terrain base material to Built In Legacy Diffuse. However the trees still puzzle me as they looked OK in Deferred Render mode before.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this:

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/tree-creator-bark-material-is-much-lighter-in-deferred-rendering-path-than-in-forward-rendering-path

They should fix that issue in few... months? weeks?